# Set screen-keyboard-enabled to false in /var/lib/gdm3/.config/dconf/user

Tags: gdm, onscreen-keyboard

How to set this variable to false in this dconf db to get rid of this annoying onscreen keybord in gdm3? I’ve tried everything but it just pops out as soon as i thouch the screen on ubuntu 18.10 login page. I’ve found this variable is set to true, so I hope changing it will disables onscreem keyboard finally (in gnome I’ve installed shell extention to disable it)

Comment: Is it touch screen?

Comment: Have you tried when you are at login screen with clicking `Screen Keyboard` from the Universal Access menu Icon drop down at the top right corner?

Comment: Touch screen/sure I’ve tried this, it doesnt help

Comment: Ok for touch screen, do you have keyboard also inbuilt?

Comment: Yes its a gpd pocket 2 laptop

Comment: have you installed `dconf-editor`? open it and then search for `keyboard-type` and turn the default option off and see. https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf3YM.jpg

Comment: Doesnt help, it seems to be a key for changing layout of onscreen keybord?